# extract date from a file name in unix using shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, grep

I am working on shell script. I want to extract date from a file name.

The file name is: `abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz`

I want to extract date from it: `2014-05-20`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
echo abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz |grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{2}'
```

**Output:**

```
2014-05-20
```

`grep` got input as `echo` stdin or you can also use `cat` command if you have these strings in a file.

`-E`  Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression.

`-o`  Show only the part of a matching line that matches PATTERN.

`[[:digit:]]` It will fetch digit only from input.

`{N}` It will check N number of digits in given string, **i.e.:** 4 for years 2 for months and days

**Most importantly it will fetch without using any separators like "_" and "." and this is why It's most flexible solution.**

Comment: Why you added `xargs` at the last?

Comment: I had something in mind but it didn't needed so I removed it @AvinashRaj

Comment: Hi,Thanks. I would like to know how do i use it in shell script?? i want to assign it to a variable

Comment: Also one more point.. my file name is full file path. /dir1/dir2/filename

Comment: @priyanka there would be no problem on that

Comment: and for using the command in variable you have to use like this http://prntscr.com/55m9p9

Comment: I tried assigning value of command to variable but getting error:

                                     cmd=`XYZ_20200824.zip | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}[[:digit:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{2}'`
echo $cmd

Comment: @MayurGite try this 
cmd=`echo XYZ_20200824.zip | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}[[:digit:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{2}'`

Comment: @Skynet - For me following command is working perfectly:

`fdate=$(echo $f | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{4}[[:digit:]]{2}[[:digit:]]{2}')`

Answer (score 12):

Using awk with custom field separator, it is quite simple:

```
echo 'abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz' | awk -F '[_.]' '{print $2}'
2014-05-20
```

Comment: I like it. Very simple and learned that -F can even be used to extract string between two separator.

Answer (score 7):

Use `grep`:

```
$ ls -1 abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz | grep -oP '[\d]+-[\d]+-[\d]+'
2014-05-20
```

- `-o` causes grep to print only the matching part
- `-P` interprets the pattern as perl regex
- `[\d]+-[\d]+-[\d]+`: stands for one or more digits followed by a dash (3 times) that matches your date.

Comment: you don't need to put `\d` inside a character class, just `grep -oP '\d+-\d+-\d+'` would be fine. For more accuracy `grep -oP '\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'` , Some grep won't support `P` in that case, use `E` instead of `P` as `grep -oE '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'`

Answer (score 2):

Here few more examples,

1. Using `cut` command (cut gives more readability like `awk` command)

```
echo "abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz" | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1
```

Output is:

```
2014-05-20
```

2. using `grep` commnad

```
echo "abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz" | grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}"
```

Output is:

2014-05-20

An another advantage of using `grep` command format is that, it will also help to fetch multiple dates like this:

```
echo "ab2014-15-12_cd_2014-05-20.tar.gz" | grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}\-[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{2}"
```

Output is:

```
2014-15-12
2014-05-20
```

Comment: Thank you.. How do I assign it to a variable and use tht var evrywherE?

Comment: DATE=$(echo "abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz" | cut -d "_" -f2 | cut -d "." -f1). similarly for other commands.

Answer (score 1):

I will use some kind of regular expression with the "grep" command, depending on how your file name is created.

If your date is always after "_" char I will use something like this.

```
ls -l | grep ‘_[REGEXP]’
```

Where REGEXP is your regular expression according to your date format.

Take a look here http://www.linuxnix.com/2011/07/regular-expressions-linux-i.html

Answer (score 1):

Multiple ways you could do it:

```
echo abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz | sed -n 's/.*_\(.*\).tar.gz/\1/p'
```

sed will extract the date and will print it.

Another way:

```
filename=abcd_2014-05-20.tar.gz
temp=${filename#*_}
date=${temp%.tar.gz}
```

Here temp will hold string in file name post "_" i.e. 2014-05-20.tar.gz
Then you can extract date by removing .tar.gz from the end.

Comment: You don't need to have a capturing group. Just `sed 's/^[^_]*_\|\..*//g'` would be 5in.