# Get date from filename and sort into folders?

Tags: bash, ssh, command-line, wget

I'm running `wget` to get data from an FTP server like this:

```
wget -r -nH -N --no-parent ftp://username:password@example.com/ -P /home/data/
```

All of the files are in a format similar to this:

```
2016_07_10_bob-randomtext.csv.gz
2016_07_11_joe-importantinfo.csv.gz
```

Right now it's putting all of these files into `/home/data/`.

What I want to do is get the time from the filename and put it into their own folders based on the date.  For example:

```
/home/data/2016_07_10/2016_07_10_bob-randomtext.csv.gz
/home/data/2016_07_11/2016_07_11_joe-importantinfo.csv.gz
```

Based off the [answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881104/extract-date-from-a-file-name-in-unix-using-shell-scripting), it is possible to get the date from a file name.  However, I'm not really sure how to turn that into a folder automatically...

Sorry if this is a bit confusing.  Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: are you OK with downloading to either /home/data or /tmp/data and then moving to /home/data/YYYY_MM_DD ? That will be easier to do. OR do you have a urgent requirement to download to YYYY_MM_DD dir directly? Good luck.

Comment: Sure, if you know how to do that, I'm totally open to downloading everything to a single folder and then moving it to where it needs to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping the download of all the files into one directory, /home/files

```
destination=/home/data
for filename in /home/files/*; do
    if [[ -f "$filename" ]]; then          # ignore it if it's a directory (not a file)
        name=$(basename "$filename")
        datedir=$destination/${name:0:10}  # first 10 characters of the filename
        mkdir -p "$datedir"                # create the directory if it doesn't exist
        mv "$filename" "$datedir"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Could you change it so the files are originally downloaded into /home/files/ and then moved into /home/data/DATE instead?  I'm not sure how to change `mv "$filename" "$date"` to make it work like that.