# Extract date from the end of filename in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I'm working with a shell program and have some files with these patterns:

```
abc_def_ghjuy_2017-09-12_15-30-40.txt
abc_def_khujdr_bv_bmg_2017-09-12_15-31-40.txt
abc_def_pkiljoy_vcdfr_2017-09-12_15-32-40.txt
abc_def_charidp_bf_mj_fr_2017-09-12_15-32-40.txt
```

How can I extract date that is in position 2 of the filename before period and save it in a variable?

Comment: potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881104/extract-date-from-a-file-name-in-unix-using-shell-scripting

Comment: Simply, execute the following command in your terminal 'ls abc* | grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}[0-9_-]+"'

Comment: Thank you sprabhakaran. Running this command give me both date and time. How can I extract just date and save it in a variable?

Comment: Is there any command in linux that I can read filename backwards, for example for position -2 which is date position and extract it?

Answer (score -1):

You can use this simple script. In `find.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ls abc_def_*-* | sed 's/abc_def\(.*\)\.txt/\1/' >> file
sed -r 's/.*(.{8})/\1/' file >> file5
mapfile -t array < file5
sudo rm -r file
```

Run this script `bash.sh`. Now your desired fields are placed as variables.

```
$ echo "${array[1]}"
$ echo "${array[2]}"
$ echo "${array[3]}"
....
```

[see the outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3EWe.png)
If you get any better solution then let me know...

Comment: Few flaws: This should not work because `array` should only exist inside `find.sh`. Maybe better as a function. Also `sudo` inside a script is a bad idea and `file` should be removable without sudo. Don't remove what is supposed to be a file with `rm -r`. Use `mktemp`. It is unclear what `bash.sh` is supposed to be.